# Hp Proliant ml310 gen8 v2 server is not recognizing western digital disks

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hp

just adquired a Hp server Proliant ML310 gen8 v2 where I work, also we adquired two brand new Westerrn Digital Discs  (P/N WD500AVVS-63ZWB0) and I tried all sata  configurations, and when I try to install any operating system, it says there is no a physical disc/drive where to install it (also on intelligent provisioning), by the way we are tying to install windows server 2012 r2

Comment: You can't just insert any old disk into an HP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HP uses special firmware on their drives.  Controllers may or may not recognize an non-HP drive.  I have had some work but in many cases the drive is not recognized.  An HP drive may clearly be a Western Digital or other brand but the controller will fail to "see" the drive as a valid HD

In some cases we were able to use the array config utility to get the drives to work but that was with older generation hardware.  It seems HP did something to force users to use their drives.

A call to HP should confirm this issue.

Having said all that, the HP firmware may add features or other function that the non-HP drive does not. Best to use vendor branded and supplied drives. Full warranty and full support.  Your data is worth the added cost

Comment: Do you have a citation for the assertion that the HP firmware adds features or other functions?  My experience is that problems with third-party drives are as often the fault of bugs in the controller as in the drives, and cost ridiculous amounts of money.

Comment: @womble  Sorry.  Simply the assertion by HP tech support or their third party service providers that such features/benefits may exist.  You certainly may be correct about HP controllers but in any case, the non-HP drives create an issue. And a large expense.

Comment: A big "cui bono" to that.